# how to target a parent element in selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nested

```
<button class="wpO6b ZQScA" type="button">
<div class="QBdPU ">
<svg aria-label="New Message" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 44 44" width="24"><path d="M33.7 44.12H8.5a8.41 8.41 0 01-8.5-8.5v-25.2a8.41 8.41 0 018.5-8.5H23a1.5 1.5 0 010 3H8.5a5.45 5.45 0 00-5.5 5.5v25.2a5.45 5.45 0 005.5 5.5h25.2a5.45 5.45 0 005.5-5.5v-14.5a1.5 1.5 0 013 0v14.5a8.41 8.41 0 01-8.5 8.5z"></path><path d="M17.5 34.82h-6.7a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.5-1.5v-6.7a1.5 1.5 0 01.44-1.06L34.1 1.26a4.45 4.45 0 016.22 0l2.5 2.5a4.45 4.45 0 010 6.22l-24.3 24.4a1.5 1.5 0 01-1.02.44zm-5.2-3h4.58l23.86-24a1.45 1.45 0 000-2l-2.5-2.5a1.45 1.45 0 00-2 0l-24 23.86z"></path><path d="M38.2 14.02a1.51 1.51 0 01-1.1-.44l-6.56-6.56a1.5 1.5 0 012.12-2.12l6.6 6.6a1.49 1.49 0 010 2.12 1.51 1.51 0 01-1.06.4z">
</path>
</svg>
</div>
</button>
```

can I use selenium to target the first parent button tag to the svg tag
I already know how to target the svg using

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//svg[@aria-label='{}']".format('New Message'))
```

actually i am unsure of the structure for example the structure can also be

```
<button><div><div><svg></svg></div></div></button>
```

I want to target the button tag is it possible then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

Refers to HTML code, from your `svg` element, the parent is `div` tag, whereas `button` is clearly seen as grandparent.

[**`Ancestor`**](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp):

> Selects all ancestors (parent, grandparent, etc.) of the current node

You can achieve the `button` using **ancestor**:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='{}']//ancestor::button[1]".format('New Message'))
```

Where `[1]` in `button[1]` is the nearest, not the first.

Don't forget to call `.click()` if you want click the element.

Answer (score 0):

To access the button element you can use Xpath:

```
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='wpO6b ZQScA']")
```

Then you should be able to click it :

```
button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the parent element which contains svg element try below xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[.//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='{}']]".format("New Message"))
```